# compare two strings of an excel having two words and write accordingly

Tags: java, string, excel, jxl

i want to compare two colums in and excel and write the result in the 3rd column.

input file is like this below
[image]

output file should be like this

[image]

This is wat i have done till now

> ```
> import java.util.List;
> import java.io.File;
> import java.io.FileInputStream;
> import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
> import java.io.IOException;
> ```

```
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.format.Colour;
import jxl.format.Pattern;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableCellFormat;
import jxl.write.WritableFont;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.write.WriteException;
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */ //variable declarations

    String element;
    static String storedElement[][]=null;
    static String Element[][]=null;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws BiffException, IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        FileInputStream fs=new FileInputStream("file location(.xls)");  
        Workbook wb=Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
        Sheet sh=wb.getSheet(0);

        Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("file location(.xls)"));
        WritableWorkbook ww= Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("file location(.xls)RENAME THE FILE here "), workbook);
        WritableSheet ws=ww.getSheet(0);

        Label label;

        //retrieving values from excel and storing in array
        storedElement = new String[sh.getColumns()][sh.getRows()];
        Element = new String[sh.getColumns()][sh.getRows()];
        //for (int j = 0; j <sh.getColumns(); j++) 
        //{ 
        int j=0; //column #0
        int q=1; //column #1
        //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 2; i < sh.getRows(); i++) //loop to run all rows

        {
            Cell cell = sh.getCell(j, i);
            Cell cell1=sh.getCell(q,i);

            storedElement[j][i] = cell.getContents();
            Element[q][i]=cell1.getContents();
            String elem =  storedElement[j][i];
            System.out.println(elem);
            String elem1= Element[q][i];
            System.out.println(elem1);
            String[] ob1=elem1.split("\n");
            System.out.println(ob1[i]);
            String[] ob = elem.split("\n");
            System.out.println(ob[i]);


        //for(int k=0;k<ob.length;k++){
            int k=0;
            while (k<ob.length){
            if (ob[k]==ob1[k]){
                    System.out.println(ob[k]);
                    System.out.println(ob1[k]);
                    label=new Label(2,i,"Valid");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(ob[k]);
                    System.out.println(ob1[k]);
                    label=new Label(2,i,"InValid");

                }
            k++;
            //add new line ??

                ws.addCell(label);
                ww.write();
                ww.close();
                workbook.close();


                }
        }

    }
}
```

i want to compare two columns in and excel and write the result in the 3rd column. here the cell contains two words where i need to write status for two words
please help me in doing it

Comment: `ob[k] == ob1[k]` is probably the issue - and the solution is probably to use equals as discussed in the duplicate.

Comment: I'm getting the same error ie in c,2 i can write only one invalid instead of valid and invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I have solved your issue.
Use below code to get result in the format you said.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.write.WriteException;
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;

public class Test {


    String element;
    static String storedElement[][] = null;
    static String Element[][] = null;


    public static void main(final String[] args) throws BiffException, IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException {


        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("file location(.xls)");
        Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
        Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(0);

        Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("file location(.xls)"));
        WritableWorkbook ww = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("file location(.xls)RENAME THE FILE here"),
            workbook);
        WritableSheet ws = ww.getSheet(0);

        Label label = null;


        Test.storedElement = new String[sh.getColumns()][sh.getRows()];
        Test.Element = new String[sh.getColumns()][sh.getRows()];

        int j = 0; // column #0
        int q = 1; // column #1

        for (int i = 1; i < sh.getRows(); i++) {
            Cell cell = sh.getCell(j, i);
            Cell cell1 = sh.getCell(q, i);

            Test.storedElement[j][i] = cell.getContents();
            Test.Element[q][i] = cell1.getContents();
            String elem = Test.storedElement[j][i];
            System.out.println(elem);
            String elem1 = Test.Element[q][i];
            System.out.println(elem1);


            String[] ob = elem1.split("\n");
            String[] ob1 = elem.split("\n");

            String valid = "valid";
            String invalid = "invalid";
            String Status = "";
            if ((ob[0].equals(ob1[0])) && (ob[1].equals(ob1[1]))) {
                Status = valid + "\n" + valid;
            } else if ((!ob[0].equals(ob1[0])) && (ob[1].equals(ob1[1]))) {
                Status = invalid + "\n" + valid;
            } else if ((!ob[0].equals(ob1[0])) && (!ob[1].equals(ob1[1]))) {
                Status = valid + "\n" + invalid;
            } else {
                Status = invalid + "\n" + invalid;
            }

            label = new Label(2, i, Status);
            ws.addCell(label);


        }
        ww.write();
        ww.close();
        workbook.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have made changes accordingly and it worked :) .

Answer (score 0):

Did you even debug your code? You should use **equals** to compare `Strings`

So replace `if (ob[k]==ob1[k]){` by `if (ob[k].equals(ob1[k])){`

(I didn't actually test your code, but this is probably the major issue)

Comment: look in the above screenshots correctly in the same cell i want two words and when im writing the second word(invalid) the first word is overwriting(valid)

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.format.Alignment;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableCellFormat;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.write.WriteException;
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;

public class Test {


    String element;
    static String storedElement[][] = null;
    static String Element[][] = null;


    public static void main(final String[] args) throws BiffException, IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException {


        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("D:/app/sweta/Book1.xls");
        Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
        Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(0);

        Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("D:/app/sweta/Book1.xls"));
        WritableWorkbook ww = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("D:/app/sweta/Book4.xls"),
            workbook);
        WritableSheet ws = ww.getSheet(0);

        Label label = null;


        Test.storedElement = new String[sh.getColumns()][sh.getRows()];
        Test.Element = new String[sh.getColumns()][sh.getRows()];

        int j = 0; // column #0
        int q = 1; // column #1



        WritableCellFormat cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(ws.getColumnFormat(j));
        cellFormat.setAlignment(Alignment.LEFT);
        cellFormat.setWrap(true);
        System.out.println(sh.getRows());
        for (int i = 1; i < sh.getRows(); i++) {

            Cell cell = sh.getCell(j, i);
            Cell cell1 = sh.getCell(q, i);

            Test.storedElement[j][i] = cell.getContents();
            Test.Element[q][i] = cell1.getContents();
            String elem = Test.storedElement[j][i];
            System.out.println(elem);
            String elem1 = Test.Element[q][i];
            System.out.println(elem1);


            String[] ob = elem1.split("\n");
            String[] ob1 = elem.split("\n");
            int l= ob.length;
         //   String valid = "valid";
        //    String invalid = "invalid";
            String Status = "";
            StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
            for(int s=0;s<l;s++){
                if (ob[s].equals(ob1[s])) {
                    sb.append("valid");
                } else {
                    sb.append("invalid");
                }
                if(s==l-1){

                }else{
                    sb.append("\n");
                }

            }

            Status = sb.toString();

            label = new Label(2, i, Status,cellFormat);
            ws.addCell(label);


        }
        ww.write();
        ww.close();
        workbook.close();
    }
}
```